# case when vs exists in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have the following query

```
SELECT TOP 10 
    CASE
        WHEN EXISTS (SELECT t1.[Code Article] FROM [Promotion] WHERE t1.datecol BETWEEN [Date Debut Promo] AND [Date Fin Promo])
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS test1,
    CASE
        WHEN [Code Article] IN (SELECT [Code Article] FROM [Promotion] WHERE datecol BETWEEN [Date Debut Promo] AND [Date Fin Promo])
            THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS test2
FROM [QlikDataWarehouse].[dbo].[Vente] t1
```

Results

[image]

Why I get test1<>test2 ? what is the diffrence between test1 and test2 ? It is not the same ?

Comment: When using subqueries, you should *always* use qualified table names.  Qualified table names are generally a good idea, but even more important with subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is simple, you are not comparing the [Code Article] value in the first subselect.

The correct syntax for the subselect would is:

```
(
  SELECT  *
  FROM     [Promotion]  
  WHERE datecol between [Date Debut Promo] and  [Date Fin Promo]
  AND t1.[Code Article] = [Code Article]
)
```

t1 in front of  the datecol has been removed and [Code Article] is joined with the outer table.

Comment: did I need to add the same one in the second subselect ?

Answer (score 0):

We don't know anything about your database so it is hard to answer that.

Use indizes and maybe a outer join. Put your subselect results to a temporary table and use those for the exists clause.